# MYSQL command Show unique values and succeeding the same values are blank or null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `users`, `leave`, and `leave_allotment`.

Is it possible to query `year` and `leave_alloted` columns to show one time unique values and others succeeding the same values change to `NULL` or `space` see Table 2 compare to Table 1?

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
| username |  start     |    end     | leave_type      | workdays | year| leave_alloted |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
| admin    | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-12 | Annual Leave    | 2.0      | 2017 |             7 |
| admin    | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-12 | Sick Leave      | 2.0      | 2017 |             7 |
| admin    | 2018-03-22 | 2018-03-22 | Leave in Lieu   | 1.0      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 0.5      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-12 | 2018-03-12 | Unpaid Leave    | 1.0      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 1.0      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 0.5      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-12 | 2018-03-12 | Emergency Leave | 3.0      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-28 | 2018-03-28 | Unpaid Leave    | 1.0      | 2018 |            14 |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
```

TABLE 2.

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
| username |    start   |    end     | leave_type      | workdays | year | leave_alloted |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
| admin    | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-12 | Annual Leave    | 2.0      | 2017 |             7 |
| admin    | 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-12 | Sick Leave      | 2.0      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-22 | 2018-03-22 | Leave in Lieu   | 1.0      | 2018 |            14 |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 0.5      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-12 | 2018-03-12 | Unpaid Leave    | 1.0      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 1.0      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-23 | 2018-03-23 | Annual Leave    | 0.5      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-12 | 2018-03-12 | Emergency Leave | 3.0      |      |               |
| admin    | 2018-03-28 | 2018-03-28 | Unpaid Leave    | 1.0      |      |               |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: I think desired results might do wonders on making your question more understandable.

Comment: That is very hard to do without a primary key. Isn't there one? Also: unique one column, unique both columns? Or are the values of the last two column always linked (2017->7 and 2018->14)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff TABLE 2 is the desired result.

Comment: You should deal with `year` and `leave_alloted` changes in your programming language, since it would be only a simple `if (lastYear != currentYear) {...}`. However, in SQL it would be a complicate `JOIN` query with `ORDER BY` and `MIN/MAX` and whatever...

Comment: This question is interesting, but very bad wrote. I answered it with and advice about how to create nice questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables. Take a look to this simple sample on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac11e/9)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( a int, b int, c int );
insert into t values
(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(1,1,1),
(2,2,2),
(2,2,2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
   case when (@previous_a<>a and @previous_b<>b) then c else null end as c,
   @previous_a:=a as a,
   @previous_b:=b as b
from t, (select @previous_a := -1,
                @previous_b := -1) T2
order by a,b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac11e/9/0)**:

```
|      c | a | b |
|--------|---|---|
|      1 | 1 | 1 |
| (null) | 1 | 1 |
| (null) | 1 | 1 |
| (null) | 1 | 1 |
|      2 | 2 | 2 |
| (null) | 2 | 2 |
```

Also, you can learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the response how can I apply that in this query? thank you SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, u.lastname) `name`, datejoin, u.username, el.start_date start, el.end_date end, el.leave_type, el.workdays, YEAR(el.submit_date) year, ela.leave_alloted FROM users u LEFT JOIN emp_leave el ON u.emp_id = el.emp_id LEFT JOIN emp_leave_allotment ela ON ela.emp_id = el.emp_id WHERE el.workdays > 0 AND u.username = 'admin' AND YEAR(el.submit_date) = ela.year ORDER BY year;